# Como arredondar hora?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tenho a seguinte função que trata uma hora que vem do banco:

```
SELECT f.chapa AS chapa,
       f.nome AS nome,
       f.secao AS cod_secao,
       f.nsecao AS desc_secao,
       c.codigo AS cod_funcao,
       c.nome AS desc_funcao,
       f.situacao AS sistuacao,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, p.ref / 24), 108) AS horas,
       p.valor AS valor
  FROM pffinanc p
       LEFT JOIN vwfunc f ON f.chapa = p.chapa
       LEFT JOIN pfuncao c ON c.codigo = f.funcao
 WHERE p.codcoligada = 1
   AND p.nroperiodo = 3
   AND p.anocomp = 2017
   AND p.mescomp = 1
   AND p.codevento IN ('156', '185', '172', '249')
   AND p.chapa = 1234
```

Ele retorna:

```
 03:56:59
 00:43:12
```

O que eu preciso é retornar somente as horas e minutos arrendando da seguinte forma:

- Se segundos **for > 30** : 03:57 (ex: 03:56:59)
- Se segundos **for < 30** : 00:43 (ex: 00:43:12)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilizando a função `DATEDIFF` você consegue um inteiro representando a diferença entre duas datas. Como o arredondamento que você deseja é na casa dos minutos, você só precisa calcular a diferença entre o momento 0 e a hora especificada somados 30 segundos, o que irá "pular" um minuto caso já tenha passado mais de 30 segundos do minuto em questão:

```
DECLARE @diferenca INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, @tempo));
```

Após isso é necessário adicionar o resultado obtido ao momento zero, obtendo assim o minuto arredondado:

```
SET @tempo = DATEADD(MINUTE, @diferenca, 0);
```

Para mostrar o tempo formatado utilize `CONVERT`:

```
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @tempo, 108);
```

---

*Aplicando à seus exemplos*

`03:56:59` mostra `03:57`:

```
DECLARE @tempo TIME = '03:56:59';
DECLARE @diferenca INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, @tempo));

SET @tempo = DATEADD(MINUTE, @diferenca, 0);

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @tempo, 108);
```

`00:43:12` mostra `00:43`:

```
DECLARE @tempo TIME = '00:43:12';
DECLARE @diferenca INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, @tempo));

SET @tempo = DATEADD(MINUTE, @diferenca, 0);

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @tempo, 108);
```

Simplificando:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, '03:56:59')), 0), 108),
       CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, '00:43:12')), 0), 108)
```

Exemplo no [**SQL Fiddler**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4981/0)

---

> [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna a contagem (inteiro com sinal) dos limites especificados de `datepart` cruzados entre os parâmetros especificados `startdate` e `enddate`.

---

> [`DATEADD`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna uma data especificada com o intervalo number especificado (inteiro assinado) adicionado à `datepart` especificada dessa data.

---

> [`CAST` e `CONVERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)
>
> Converte uma expressão de um tipo de dados para outro.

---

Adaptado da resposta da pergunta [**T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667041/3388148) do [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Posta um [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), vai ficar bacana!

Comment: @Marconi opa, valeu a sugestão, coloquei no Fiddle!

Comment: @otaciojb pra aplicar na sua `query` eu preciso saber qual o tipo de dado da coluna `REF`

Comment: Com o comando que vc aplicou abaixo simplificado deu certo aqui, Obrigado, já marquei como reposta, coloquei da seguinte forma: CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, 30, (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, P.REF/24), 108)))), 0), 108),

Comment: Seu sql fiddle está dando este erro. Favor edita-lo. testado em 09/07/2019